# glDebugMessageCallback more detailed information

Tags: c++, opengl

Everywhere I read that `glDebugMessageCallback` is the better solution to get errors, so I implemented it. So far so good. And I am getting indeed more detailed information about what's going on. Currently on NVIDIA it looks f.e. like this:

> DebugLog: In source API, type OTHER, id 131185, severity : NONE,
> message Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 3 (bound to
> GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (0), and
> GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STREAM_DRAW) will use VIDEO
> memory as the source for buffer object operations.

Really nice, indeed- however, I miss one thing- I can't indicate here where exactly this happened.

If I use old style method with a macro like this:

`#define CHECK_GL_ERROR() CheckGLError(__FILE__, __LINE__)`
and
`glGetError()`

it's far less detailed and a mess in the code- BUT! I can track it more easily down to the line or call it happened, at least when debugging myself.

Of course, if I reduce the log level to something more severe, it is probably also easier to identify the origin, since there are less functions in question, yet, depending on code I find this a bit imprecise to find a specific function.

So my question is now- is there a way to tell what exactly the callback triggered, the function or the perhaps the line in the code, like in the old method (that is, now without adding a manual breakpoint/debug)??

I would find that very handy, especially when considering a situation in which someone who is maybe just using the software could provide me a log only for a problem I can't reproduce myself.

PS: Could someone enlighten me what "id" is for? I found a lot of tutorials and explanations, also read the docs but I still don't see of what use it is for debugging.

Comment: I'd consider using an OpenGL debugger for debugging. The Debug Callback can provide hints, but you need to indeed find what part of your code triggered it. There are also call tracers that can log every call you make to OpenGL to inspect later. In general, I'd use everything I could. Just because you use the debug callback doesn't mean you can't use glGetError and vice versa.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I want to have the most useful and informative logs if I can't debug it myself and get only reports from users f.e. And aside that, it would still make things easier :)

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get the "line" printed as well using `glDebugMessageCallback`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways that help you identify where the error comes from:

First, you can `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS)` to ensure that errors are thrown in the scope of the function that produces them. When you now set a breakpoint in the error callback function, you'll see through the callstack where the error originates.

Second: OpenGL allows you to associate names and scopes with each OpenGL object. This allows you to specify names for, let's say, a buffer. Have a look [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output#Scoping_messages) for more details.

Comment: yes, I know, but at the moment I want to see how to get the max out of "unattended" logging . Will read me through the scopes :)

Comment: If you really want to know during logging where you are, you can produce a stacktrace yourself (depends on your compiler how this works).